# syntax error when using eval for dynamic array initiation

Tags: arrays, bash

```
var=(a b c)
eval "${var[0]}=(1 2)"
```

then I got an error message says

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `1'
```

So what does the syntax error mean and how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the script in `bash`? It works for me.

Comment: @Cyrus he want's to set `a=(1 2)`

Comment: Why not just use associative arrays?

Comment: Please show the output of `echo $0 $SHELL ; bash --version | head -1`

Comment: @chiroba, It works for me too, (bash *v4.3.36*), but the error is reproducible if the quotes are removed:  `unset var a ; var=(a b c) ; eval ${var[0]}=(1 2)`.

Comment: I am trying to set a=(1 2); the command works with my ubuntu, but not with my CentOS 6: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Your example makes it look like you simply want to create multiple, identical arrays using a hard-coded list of values. That seems rather pointless, and anything more complicated will 1) require a different solution and 2) be a huge warning sign that you are using the wrong language anyway.

Comment: `eval` is the wrong tool for this job, unless you're willing to exercise far more caution in its use than the code in the question implies. Use namerefs (`declare -n`) to be able to assign to an arbitrarily-named object (arrays included); see the section of BashFAQ #6 on [indirect assignments via reference variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables).

Comment: @agc The value of `$SHELL` won't tell you anything relevant; it contains the name of the user's login shell, not the identity of the active shell.

Comment: @chepner, I dunno... `$SHELL` might show what shell the user *believed* was active.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to understand how is `eval` affecting the line you wrote is to replace `eval` with `echo`. Issuing the command with echo, it shows this:

```
$ var=(a b c)
$ echo "${var[0]}=(1 2)"
a=(1 2)
```

As you can see, the command that will be executed by the eval line will set the variable `$a` not the variable `$var`. In fact, if for any reason, the value of `${var[0]}` becomes `1` (as you are trying to do) the `eval` line will become:

```
$ var=(1 2)
$ echo "${var[0]}=(1 2)"
1=(1 2)
```

Line that if it gets `eval`ed will trigger the error you see.

The solution depends on exactly what you are willing to get done.

If it is to change the value of variable `$a`, which is stored inside `${var[0]}`, then, you may either use:

```
declare -a "${var[0]}=(1 2)"
```

Which, if `${var[0]}` is `1`, will emit this error:

```
 bash: declare: `1=(1 2)': not a valid identifier
```

Which is a more meaningful message IMO.

Or, if you really want to avoid the use of eval:

```
#! /bin/bash
var=(a b c)
values=(1 2)
read -ra "${var[0]}" <<< "${values[@]}"
declare -p "${var[0]}"
```

Will print:

```
declare -a a=([0]="1" [1]="2")
```

If the `$values` may contain spaces or newlines (or a value that a modified IFS could contain) you will need a more complex script:

```
#! /bin/bash
var=(a b c)
values=("1 2" "3 4")
i=0
while IFS='' read -rd $'\0';do
    declare "${var[0]}[$i]"="$REPLY" ;
    ((i++));
done < <( printf '%s\0' "${values[@]}")

declare -p "${var[0]}"
```

Or, for more recent bash versions (since bash-4.4), you could use readarray's `-t` option (to remove the delimiter):

```
#! /bin/bash
var=(a b c)
values=("1 2" "3 4")

IFS='' readarray -td $'\0' "${var[0]}" < <(printf '%s\0' "${values[@]}")

declare -p "${var[0]}"
```

Comment: The `read` command doesn't quite work they way you want it to. Here strings aren't subject to word splitting at all, so `read` is simply splitting the string on whitespace, rather than respecting the boundary between array elements. Try this with `values=("1 2" "3 4")`; `a` ends up with 4 elements, not 2.

Comment: @chepner True: read is affected by the value of IFS. In that case we need to delimit the array values with a NUL. That will require the use of a heavier gun: a NUL terminated process substitution. In that case, read will keep the values correctly separated with no problem. Please try the added script.

Comment: Ugly :), but it will work. `bash` 4.4 was officially release about 6 months ago; no need to refer to the alpha release now.